# PowerShell: How to use / import scriptblock from another ps1 file

Tags: powershell

I know we can import functions from another file.

But is it possible to use a scriptblock existing in another .ps1 file?

file1.ps1

```
$scriptblock = {...}
```

file2.ps1

```
#I wanna use the scriptblock from file1.ps1 other than copy then paste

Start-Job -Name jobname -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

Comment: You may read [about dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.1#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing).